# NGXS. How to test service methods (toHaveBeenCalled) after dispatch action

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngxs

I try the run test, but the test fails every time. What I do wrong

**1. My store action**

```
@Action(GetDataAction)
  getDataList(ctx: StateContext<any>) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    return this.service.getData()...
```

**2. Add init variables.**
Here I am creating a service variable in a test case. As I understand after that, my service becomes one for everyone.

```
    describe('Store', () => {
      let actions$: Observable<any>;
      let store: Store;
      let service: SomeService;
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpClientModule, NgxsModule.forRoot([AppStore])],
        });
        store = TestBed.inject(Store);
        actions$ = TestBed.inject(Actions);
        service = new SomeService(null);
      });
```

**3. Add test**

```
  it(should be run service.getData() after action new GetDataAction()', (done) => {

    const spy = spyOn(service, 'getData').and.callFake(() => {
      return EMPTY;
    });

    store.dispatch(new GetDataAction()).subscribe(() => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
```

`Error text:  Store > should be run service.getData() after action new GetDataAction() Expected spy getData to have been called. Error: Expected spy getData to have been called. at <Jasmine> at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/store/store.spec.ts:41:19) at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:183:1) at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:122:1)`

Comment: How are you accessing `service` in your test case? You may be calling two difference instances. i.e. (the store could have instance A and your test case is using instance B).

Comment: Hi, kyle. I added more Information. Thank you!